# Export Database's Table from button Laravel 5.3 into .sql files

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5.3, database-backups

i had already try this code in my Model :

```
    $file = storage_path('table.sql');
    DB::statement("SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '".addslashes($file)."' FROM table_name");
```

but if i opened table.sql in my text editor, i got this :

> 41    9   Not Present Not Present Not Present 2016-05-09  18:45:56    \N
>   42  5   Come    \N  \N  2016-11-09  18:46:21    \N
>   43  25  Come    Go Home \N  2016-11-09  18:46:29    19:24:33
>   47  25  Late    Go Home \N  2016-11-10  08:43:21    08:46:19
>   48  26  Late    \N  \N  2016-12-01  08:46:28    \N
>   66  5   Late    \N  \N  2017-01-01  19:23:57    \N
>   67  1   Late    Go Home \N  2017-02-03  15:23:32    15:46:29
>   68  3   Late    Go Home \N  2017-02-14  07:14:07    07:16:56
>   69  5   Late    \N  \N  2017-02-14  07:48:47    \N
>   70  6   Late    Go Home \N  2017-02-14  08:04:25    08:10:12
>   71  7   Late    \N  \N  2017-02-14  08:19:31    \N
>   72  8   Late    \N  \N  2017-02-20  07:44:22    \N
>   73  10  Late    \N  \N  2017-02-20  07:54:54    \N
>   74  5   Late    \N  \N  2017-02-20  07:56:44    \N
>   75  3   Late    \N  \N  2017-02-20  07:57:01    \N
>   76  2   Late    \N  \N  2017-02-20  08:07:24    \N
>   77  1   Late    Go Home \N  2017-02-20  08:08:30    08:19:25
>   78  24  Late    Go Home \N  2017-02-20  08:20:43    08:27:47
>   79  22  Late    \N  \N  2017-02-20  08:28:31    \N
>   80  21  Late    Go Home \N  2017-02-20  08:29:13    08:30:23
>   81  18  Late    Go Home \N  2017-02-20  08:32:12    08:32:50
>   82  17  Late    Go Home \N  2017-02-20  08:34:21    09:05:19
>   83  25  Late    Go Home \N  2017-02-20  08:53:02    08:53:24
>   84  23  Late    Go Home \N  2017-02-20  08:55:55    08:58:47
>   85  19  Late    \N  \N  2017-02-20  09:04:16    \N
>   86  15  Late    \N  \N  2017-02-20  10:30:37    \N
>   87  13  Late    \N  \N  2017-02-20  10:31:58    \N
>   88  12  Late    \N  \N  2017-02-20  10:32:28    \N

it's totally difference when i exported my table using export menu in my PHPMyAdmin and opened it in my text editor.

please you guys help me to solving my problem... or you guys have some other ways...

Thanks

Comment: I think you are exporting the select results, not creating SQL file. Searching Stackoverflow.com gives this one: https://github.com/bradcornford/Backup

Comment: https://github.com/nWidart/DbExporter This one exports into Laravel seeds.. use it if you like. Maybe some searching before asking is helpful.